# Message text from GetMessageW or NtUserGetMessage

Tags: windbg, getmessage

I have a process that is spawned as a background process, that for some reason seems to throw up a message box in the background. So the process hangs, and I can't get the message.

Can anyone tell me how I can get the text in this message via WinDbg, or any other way? This is a x64 native c++ process on Windows Server 2008 x64.

The top of the stack on the "hanging" thread (0) is:

```
00000000`0012fdc8 00000000`76ad9e9e USER32!NtUserGetMessage+0xa
00000000`0012fdd0 00000001`40bb2b04 USER32!GetMessageW+0x34
[..internal code...]
00000000`0012ff60 00000000`7707c521 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
00000000`0012ff90 00000000`00000000 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is the process created by a service? If not, what do you mean by "background"?

Answer (score 5):

It is not displaying a message - it is simple windows message receive/process/dispatch loop. Windows message being an event, like timer or mouse move. So, the thread is not really stuck, it's just that GetMessage blocks if there were no messages posted to this thread'd message queue.